# Edited tag wiki, but didn't receive tally to research assistant badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing, badges, tag-wikis

I haven't found any posts discussing not receiving a tally for tag wiki edits. I have edited at least 4 tag wikis, received approval and have not seen any updates to my research assistant tally?

Received point after approval here:

[image]

No updates to tally, though:

[image]

Anyone know why I haven't received any points towards my research assistant badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Research Assistant badge requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121517/research-assistant-badge-requirements), is it possible that you have only been editing tag wiki excerpts and not the body of those tag wikis?

I just checked a couple of your tag wiki edits and they look like they were excerpt only.